# GcmListenerService not running if closed by back press

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM service in my app and implemented it using the steps given in official documentation. I receive notifications alright when the app is in foreground or is in background (home button pressed). But the problem occurs when I press back when the app is in foreground, hence finishing the app I suppose. In log cat I get this error 
    `broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=in.mobile.connectree.collegefeed (has extras)`

Since there is no mention of any explicit broadcast receiver in the documentation, I haven't used it anywhere. Is that a problem here? Any permission I need or flags?
AndroidManifest file has these entries

```
<!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="in.mobile.connectree.collegefeed" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="in.mobile.connectree.collegefeed.service.GcmListenerServiceClass"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->

    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="in.mobile.connectree.collegefeed.service.InstanceIDListenerServiceClass"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="in.mobile.connectree.collegefeed.service.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

Comment: Do you have the required permissions in your manifest, RECEIVE and WAKE_LOCK? https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i am using '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />'
i cannot find any permission for RECEIVE

Comment: What dependencies are you using for GCM?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="in.mobile.connectree.collegefeed.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Comment: I was asking about the dependencies in your app/build.gradle file. I'd also include the code you are using to handle the received messages.